# Enum class with name and ordinal constructors

Tags: kotlin, enums

Coming from java background, I'm wondering how do you handle Enums with string names and int ordinals.

I notice that property name and ordinal is built-in into enums as I tried to specify a constructor and it gave shadow warning. Here's my code.

```
enum class Department {
    ACCOUNTING(0, "Accounting"),
    SALES(1, "Sales"),
    HR(2, "Human Resource")
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that Above code compiles with a warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `toString()` for the specific `enum` class (HR) that you want to return a different value for. You can also override `toString()` for you parent `enum` and make it return a `String` with only the first letter capitalized, that way you can keep the naming convention intact.

```
enum class Department {
    ACCOUNTING,
    SALES,
    HR {
        override fun toString() = "Human Resource"
    };

// capitalize first letter
override fun toString() =
    super.toString().toLowerCase().capitalize()
}
```

you can then simply call `toString()` or pass it as string.

```
fun main() {
   val hrString = HR.toString()
   println(hrString) // Human Resource
   println(HR) // Human Resource
   println(ACCOUNTING) // Accounting
   println(SALES) //Sales
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html) (bottom of the page):

> Every enum constant has properties to obtain its name and position in the enum class declaration.

In your example that means that you can specify your enum as:

```
enum class Department {
    ACCOUNTING,
    SALES,
    HR
}
```

Then

```
Department.values().forEach { println("${it.ordinal}: ${it.name}") }
```

will print

```
0: ACCOUNTING
1: SALES
2: HR
```

---

To add a display name (like `"Human Resources"`) to your class, I think your best option is to add a property to your constructor:

```
enum class Department(val displayName: String) {
    ACCOUNTING("Accounting"),
    SALES("Sales"),
    HR("Human Resources")
}
```

However, if you really want to stick to this short form, you could simply change the name accordingly:

```
enum class Department {
    Accounting,
    Sales,
    `Human Resources`
}
```

Note the back ticks to allow for spaces in your display name. I would personally not do this, since `` Department.`Human Resources` `` is cumbersome to type and somewhat difficult to read (at least in my opinion).

Comment: just wondering if you could specify a user friendly string, for instance `ACCOUNTING -> "Accounting"`, `HR -> "Human Resource"`while keeping the short form intact, that was the idea behind leveraging the existing name property, ideas?

Comment: Personally, I would add a property `displayName` or something in the constructor. But if you really want to stick to this short form, you could name your elements accordingly (however that might get unclear to read and cumbersome to type). I'll edit an example into my answer.

Comment: It's not considered a convention to use upper-case-only names for enums in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for your correction! Should have checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Same as a `class` in `kotlin`, you can specify properties in the `enum` `class` `constructor`. For example

```
enum class Color( val r: Int, val g: Int, val b: Int){ 
     RED(255, 0, 0), ORANGE(255, 165, 0), YELLOW(255, 255, 0); 
}
```

As you already know [Enum](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Enum.kt) class(***The common base class of all enum classes***) have built in `name` and `ordinal` properties. these properties are defined as follows

```
/** Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration. */
public final val name: String

/** Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, 
 *  where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). */
public final val ordinal: Int
```

Please note that they are marked `final`, meaning you can not `override` them. 
So I suggest that instead of trying to change values of these properties as defined by the `class`, you should declare your own properties in the `enum` and use their values instead.

Comment: so it's fine that I can override the existing name and ordinal property in enum, I was thinking there should be some way to leverage some built-in functionality without specifying a constructor.

Comment: Enum class actually have ordinal and name properties, but you dont pass them in the constructor. Name is your constants name and ordinal is constant's position in enum. I will update the answer.

Comment: @AppDeveloper The name and ordinal of an enum in Kotlin is handled the same as in Java. The constant name is the name and the order of declaration determines the ordinal.

Comment: Slwa, agreed, in Java I've to provide name and ordinal as a property, there's no built-in AFAIK, in kotlin I noticed it's built-in and available to use but then providing a constructor and shadowing the inherited properties are throwing me off.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Java enums also have built-in `name()` and `ordinal()` getters, just like in Kotlin. And they are final, just like in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty stale, but a key piece of advice seems to be missing from the answers...

If the ordinal is an important public piece of information that should be clearly visible at the point of definition, then YES pass it as an explicit argument, say in a constructor argument ordinalCheck.  I believe enum's wacky initialization order makes the ordinal appear to be zero inside the constructor (I'm not sure about that), but you can at least introduce a static init block (or companion object init for Kotlin) to check at class initialization time that each enum instance has an ordinalCheck (val/final field) equal to its ordinal.  Then you can be assured that if the class has been loaded in a test since the last time someone modified the file, the ordinal value provided in ordinalCheck definitely agrees with the ordinal assigned by the enum mechanism.

An alternative scheme uses a static counter, incremented and compared against the ordinalCheck in an assertion inside the enum's constructor.  In that scheme, the ordinalCheck doesn't have to be in its own field.